# Too Much White Space in Border Box After Line Break — Mobile

Tags: html, css

This unorganized list looks/works as desired; however, on mobile, the line breaks (as it should) and the border-box no longer fits the text as expected. No doubt I've gone about this the wrong way, but I can't figure out how to implement the list so that text borders are without unneeded white-space.

[WORKING CORRECTLY ON DESKTOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyj87.jpg)

[ON MOBILE W/ ADDED ARROW TO SHOW ISSUE (IMGUR LINK)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmALR.jpg)

```html
<style>
.list-container {
 text-align: left;
}
.emph-list li {
 list-style-type: none; 
}
.emph-list .special-font {
 border-style: double;
 border-color: #BB133E;
   border-width: 3 !important;
 padding: 5px 5px 3px 5px;
 color: #002147;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 10px !important;
 margin-right: 10px !important;
   font-family: "FilmCryptic";
   font-size: 28px;
   

}
#emph-list-title {
   font-size: 32px !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
   font-family: "FilmCryptic";
}
</style>

<div class="list-container">
<h1 id="emph-list-title">Who Needs a Proofreader?</h1>
<ul class="emph-list">
 <li class="special-font">Anyone with a Resume</li>
 <li class="special-font">Fiction/Non-Fiction Authors</li>
 <li class="special-font">Bloggers</li>
 <li class="special-font">Business Owners</li>
 <li class="special-font">College or Graduate Students</li>
 <li class="special-font">Entrepreneurs</li>
 <li class="special-font">Graphic Designers</li>
 <li class="special-font">Journalists</li>
 <li class="special-font">Marketing Managers</li>
 <li class="special-font">Podcasters</li>
 <li class="special-font">Script Writers</li>
 <li class="special-font">Transcriptionists</li>
 <li class="special-font">Web Content Creators</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I've tried adjusting `"white-space"`, `"word-wrap"` and `"display."` I have also tried to rewrite the code a few times.

Comment: try to reduce the font-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use responsive media Query for this, Change media width according to your need

```
@media (max-width: 7678px){
.emph-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.emph-list .special-font {
  font-size: 20px;
  }
 #emph-list-title {
  font-size: 26px !important;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

**css**

```
.emph-list .special-font {
   word-wrap: anywhere;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Removes padding behaviour on widths */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) which you can write with `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`.

```css
ul {
  width: 50%;
}

li {
 border-style: double;
 border-color: #BB133E;
  border-width: 3 !important;
 padding: 5px 5px 3px 5px;
 color: #002147;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 10px !important;
 margin-right: 10px !important;
  font-family: "FilmCryptic";
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>College or Graduate Students</li>
  <li>College&nbsp;or&nbsp;Graduate&nbsp;Students</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below style property for mobile device

```
@media (max-width: 560px) {
     .emph-list .special-font{ word-break: break-all; }
}
```